# AspectJ pointcut on nested generics?

Tags: java, generics, aop, aspectj

I have this class:

```java
public final class Helper<T> {

   public static <TYPE> Helper.Builder<TYPE> builder(final Class<TYPE> objectClass) {
        return new Helper.Builder<>(objectClass);
   }

   public static final class Builder<E> {

      private String name;

      public Builder<E> withName(final String name) {
         this.name = name;
         return this
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to create an interceptor like so:

```java
@Around("execution(* com.test.Helper.Builder.withName(String,..))")
public Object interceptor(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
   System.out.println("intercepted!");
   return joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
}
```

I tried testing this to see if my output gets printed:

```java
public class Dummy {}

Helper<Dummy> helper = Helper
   .builder(Dummy.class)
   .withName("name")
```

but my interceptor never gets called. I have made sure that the package is correct and I got this to work on other classes without generics. I read online and tried to modify the pointcut to `"execution(* com.test.Helper+.Builder+.withName(String,..))"` but I get a syntax error:

```
Invalid pointcut 'execution(* com.test.Helper+.Builder+.withName(String,..))':
  org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ParserException
```

What's going on?

edit: For anyone who might have the same error, the problem was literally the version. I upgraded from aspectjweaver 1.6.2 to 1.8 and it works fine.

Comment: Your Java code contains multiple errors and does not even compile, before even starting to add the aspect. Fix it, please, then I can take a look. Don't just post pseudo code here for something as complicated as generics. I could make your code compile in at least two different ways, but both would involve changing code and speculating how you might have done it.

Comment: I often include ellipses („…“) to make it more or less clear that members like your *`Helper.Builder< E > ( Class< E > )`* constructor have been elided.

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***: This is a red herring…

```
Invalid pointcut 'execution(* com.test.Helper+.Builder+.withName(String,..))':
  org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ParserException
```

---

***The long-winded version***

> „*What's going on?*“

Too many things going on in your example code are syntactically illegal. So I'll cut right to the point with the most egregious illegality.

You define your *`Builder`* to return a *`Builder`*…

```
Builder< E > withName( … ) {
    … 
    return this;
}
```

But then you try to assign it to something that's ***not*** a *`Builder`*…

```
…
Helper<Dummy> helper = Helper
   .builder(Dummy.class)
   .withName("name")
…
```

AspectJ aside, [*here is a syntactically-legal demonstration of how I propose*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1u9) you implement your *`Helper`* ***before*** AOP even enters into the picture…

```
…
public class Helper { 
    
    public static < C > Helper.Builder< C > builder( final Class< C > objectClass ) { 
        
        return new Helper.Builder< C >( objectClass );
    }
    
    public static class Builder< D > { 
        
        private String name;
        
        private Class< D > objectClass;
        
        public Builder( Class< D > objectClass ) { this.objectClass = objectClass; }
        
        public Builder< D > withClass( final String name ) { this.name = name; return this;  }
    }
}
```

[*I demonstrate experimentally that the above implementation*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1u9) successfully compiles. This demonstrates the correct way to call it…

```
…
Helper.Builder builder = Helper.builder( DeduperAnswer.class ).withClass( "foo" );
…
```